# Missing Emoji in Emacs and Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts, emacs, emoji

I've had this issue on **Mojave**, and it remains now that I upgraded to **Big Sur** with a *clean install*. Can't find anything about it on Google.

All emoji are working just fine *everywhere* on my system, *except* for **Emacs** and **Firefox** where some of them are replaced with a *monochrome version*. A few examples below.

Working everywhere, *including* Emacs and Firefox:

Working everywhere, *except* for Emacs and Firefox:

[image: Screenshot taken while writing this post in Firefox]
*Screenshot taken while writing this post in Firefox*

There are no duplicates in my Font Book. Emacs and Firefox are both set to use Apple Color Emoji. Issue persists with a new init.el in Emacs, and a new profile in Firefox.

Any idea on how to solve this, please pretty please?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it might help someone else with these issues.

In **Emacs**, add this line to your `init.el`:

```
(set-fontset-font t '(#x1f000 . #x1faff) (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji"))
```

In **Firefox**, go to `about:config`.

Search for `font.name-list.sans-serif.x-unicode` and replace its value with `Apple Color Emoji`.

You should now have all emoji displayed just fine in both programs. :)

Have a great day!